# Segfault from /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib (flagged for deletion by author)

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm running the following C code.

```
void manual_enter(int * state_count, char * states, char * alphabet, char * start_state, char * accept_states) {
   int counter;

   printf("Please enter the number of states in the DFA. ");
   scanf("%d", state_count);
   states = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * (*state_count) );
   printf("\n!");
   counter = 0;
   for(counter = 0; counter < *state_count; counter++) {
      printf("\n!");
      printf("\nPlease enter state: %d", counter);
      scanf("%c", states[counter]);
      printf("%c", states[counter]);
   }

   return;

}
```

I receive a segfault after the 2nd exclamation point but before the prompt to enter a given state number. I ran in gdb to get a backtrace and this is what I got:

```
 (gdb) bt
 #0  0x00007fff8b313fda in ?? () from /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
 #1  0x00007fff5fbff360 in ?? ()
 #2  0x00007fff88db1fbb in __fread () from /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
 Backtrace stopped: frame did not save the PC
```

I'm a programming novice, so it may well be that I'm approaching this debugging this all wrong. Any help or tips for how to approach this would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The function receives `states` as a parameter. Why are you assigning it with `malloc()`?

Comment: [don't cast the result of malloc in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: Thanks folks. Easy fix. I'm still somewhat mystified as to why I received the segfault where I did and got the backtrace that I did. But it now seems that the title of the posting is pretty unrelated to the problem/solution. Should I delete the question, retitle, or is there some other way to handle situations like this?

Comment: When you cause undefined behavior, the error can happen anywhere. You might not even get an error at all.

Comment: Deleting would be the more reasonable. The code is not good and it will not help others. It is the n*100th incarnation of the same fault.

Comment: Hokey doke; I wasn't able to delete but I've flagged the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument corresponding to `%c` in `scanf()` has to be a pointer:

```
  scanf(" %c", &states[counter]);
```

You should have gotten a compiler warning about this.

You should also put a space before `%c` so it will skip over whitespace before reading the character. Otherwise, every other `state` will contain a newline character.

I wonder why you're allocating `states` when the function receives this as an argument. If the function is supposed to allocate the `states` array itself and return it to the caller (like it does with `state_count), the argument should be`char **states`. Then you would do:

```
*states = malloc(sizeof(char) * (*state_count));
```

All the other references to `states` in the function will also need to be changed to `*states`.